# CVS/SVN Detailed Commit History

Tags: svn, cvs

Recently my company has tasked me with analyzing our SVN and (formerly) CVS repositories to quantify the amount of "work" (in terms of LOC Deltas) was done on behalf of various customers (using contents of the commit log). For SVN, this wasn't too bad to write a simple script for, going something like this:

1. Checkout the most recent branch
2. Check the logs to determine
   previous version
3. Checkout the previous version
4. Diff the two
   with some LOC tool
5. Repeat steps 2 through 4

For CVS, it's not so clear what the steps are, as it's difficult to know what the previous version was and ensure that it's not a development branch (which, if counted, would lead to double counting code).

I'm curious if there are any tools that exists which either does this for me (in both SVN and/or CVS), or would make it simpler. Searching around I found: http://www.red-bean.com/cvs2cl/ , but the XML output still doesn't seem to resolve the issue of knowing the order of commits. I imagine there must be some library out there, since http://www.akhphd.au.dk/~bertho/cvsgraph/ would require access to all the information I would want.

Answer (score 0):

CVS did not have any concept of a patch or commit to multiple files before about 2005 (when 'commitids' were added). This means that the patches have to be fabricated based on other data in the repository.

The best available tool for this fabrication appears to be [`cvsps`](https://gitorious.org/cvsps), it will investigate your repository via `cvs rlog` and manufacture a sequence of commits (as patch files) for the repository based mostly on the date and time of the file updates.

Another option, that may seem strange at first glance, is to convert the CVS repository to another VCS tool. All the current ones can appear to work on a 'snapshot' principal (as you used with SVN). The converter does the 'heavy lifting' of guessing the commits.

Just as an aside, I hope your "LOC Tool" does something sane with a commit that says "Refactor to improve performance" and has a MINUS 2000 lines total count.